# Sqlite database tables not showing up even though I have the identifier.sqlite file in pycharm

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pycharm

I am working on a project with a partner, and his database is working fine, but mine (2016 mac pro)  just shows the file for some reason, and it creates another identifier.sqlite file outside the project every time I pull, so I always have one empty identifier.sqlite file, but that does not seem like a problem. I have included some images below for reference, if anyone needs more please let me know!

[initial DB without drag and drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAMFZ.png)
[After trying drag and drop method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqm7d.png)

this is one of the errors I got when i tried the drag-and-drop:     cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database

I have tried deleting the project and cloning again but did not work, and I have also tried dragging the identifier.sqlite file into the empty database column, clicking "+" -> "sqLite" -> schemas -> all schemas --> apply --> ok and then refreshing the database, but it just shows the DDL and an identifier file with a table called sqlite_master, which is basically empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to open a sqlite database file inside your code editor?

Comment: @JohnGordon It seems very efficient, and my partner is doing it that way, so I wanted to do it the same way as him to avoid any confusion. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your partner opened a `.sqlite` file, and not a `.sql` file?  Those are very different things.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, we opened up a .sqlite file. For some reason his works and mine does not

Comment: Hold up!!!!! I just did some random stuff and it fixed!!!